# How do I make the EditText such that it gets the value of the element of the ArrayList that you long-clicked?

Tags: java, android

```
package sg.edu.rp.c345.p04;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class toDo extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    EditText toDoEditText;
    Button submitButton;
    ListView toDoListView;

    ArrayList<String> toDoTasks;
    ArrayAdapter<String> taskArrayAdapter;

    static final private int SORT_TASKS = Menu.FIRST;
    static final private int REVERSE_SORT_TASKS = Menu.FIRST + 1;
    static final private int REMOVE_TASKS = Menu.FIRST + 2;
    static final private int EDIT_TASKS = Menu.FIRST + 3;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        toDoEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.toDoEditText);
        submitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitButton);
        toDoListView = getListView();
        toDoTasks = new ArrayList<String>();
        taskArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, toDoTasks);

        toDoListView.setAdapter(taskArrayAdapter);

        registerForContextMenu(toDoListView);

        submitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (toDoEditText.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                    return;
                }
                String task = toDoEditText.getText().toString();
                toDoTasks.add(task);
                taskArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                toDoEditText.setText("");
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu optionsMenu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(optionsMenu);
        // Create and add new menu items.
        MenuItem itemSort = optionsMenu.add(0, SORT_TASKS, Menu.NONE,
                R.string.sortAll);
        MenuItem itemReverseSort = optionsMenu.add(0, REVERSE_SORT_TASKS,
                Menu.NONE, R.string.sortReverse);
        MenuItem itemRem = optionsMenu.add(0, REMOVE_TASKS, Menu.NONE,
                R.string.removeAll);
        itemSort.setIcon(R.drawable.sort_btn);
        itemReverseSort.setIcon(R.drawable.reverse_sort_btn);
        itemRem.setIcon(R.drawable.remove_btn);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem optionItem) {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(optionItem);
        switch (optionItem.getItemId()) {
        case (SORT_TASKS): {

            // Perform the necessary task to sort the items in the ArrayList
            // alphabetically
            // Hint: use Collections.sort()
            Collections.sort(toDoTasks);
            taskArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            return true;
        }
        case (REVERSE_SORT_TASKS): {

            // Perform the necessary task to sort the items in the ArrayList
            // reverse alphabetically
            // Hint: use Collections.reverse()
            Collections.reverse(toDoTasks);
            taskArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            return true;
        }
        case (REMOVE_TASKS): {

            // Perform the necessary actions to remove ALL the tasks in the
            // ArrayList
            toDoTasks.clear();
            taskArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            return true;
        }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Choose your action");
        menu.add(0, REMOVE_TASKS, Menu.NONE, R.string.removeItem);
        menu.add(0, EDIT_TASKS, Menu.NONE, R.string.editItem);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case (REMOVE_TASKS): {
            AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo menuInfo;
            menuInfo = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
            final int removeIndex = menuInfo.position;
            toDoTasks.remove(removeIndex);
            taskArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;
        }
        case (EDIT_TASKS): {
            AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo menuInfo;
            menuInfo = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
            final int editIndex = menuInfo.position;
            final String editText = menuInfo.toString();

            AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

            alert.setTitle("Edit Task");
            alert.setMessage("Edit Task Message");

            // Set an EditText view to get user input
            final EditText editInput = new EditText(this);
            alert.setView(editInput);

            alert.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int whichButton) {
                            String editTask = editInput.getText().toString();
                            // Do something with value!
                            toDoTasks.set(editIndex, editTask);
                            taskArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });

            alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int whichButton) {
                            // Canceled.
                        }
                    });

            alert.show();
        }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

How do I make the EditText such that it gets the value of the element of the ArrayList that you long-clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`OnItemClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html). In the method write something like:

```
toDoEditText.setText(view.getText());
```

Here view is your view of the item. You should implement method getText() by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an [**AutoCompleteTextView**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html) works better